# Offlineimap run with launchd can't find python modules used to hide password

Tags: python, macos, imap, launchd

I am trying to get [offlineimap](http://www.offlineimap.org) to run in the background on OSX El Capitan using launchd.

Here is my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.andypierz.offlineimap.plist</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/offlineimap</string>
    <string>-u</string>
    <string>quiet</string>
   </array>
   <key>StartInterval</key>
   <integer>60</integer>
   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/Users/Andy/.Mailder/offlineimap_err.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
      <string>/Users/Andy/.Mailder/offlineimap.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This loads and runs, however my logs show offlineimap is running into an error:

```
OfflineIMAP 6.7.0
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
ERROR: No module named keyring
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: No module named keyring
```

To avoid have my passwords in plaintext in my .offlineimaprc I am using the python keyring method described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OfflineIMAP#python2-keyring).

When I run offlineimap from the terminal it works fine and I am able to use the python keyring to import my passwords with no problem. Similarly, when I run offlineimap as a cronjob this also seems to work without incident. However, cron is deprecated on OSX so I would prefer to use launchd.

Relevant parts of my .offlineimaprc:

```
[general]
accounts = personal, work
maxsyncaccounts = 3
pythonfile = /Users/Andy/offlineimap.py

[Repository personalRemote]
type = IMAP
remotehost = myhost.com
remoteuser = myalperson@email.com
remotepasseval = keyring.get_password('email', 'personal')

[Repository workRemote]
type = IMAP
remotehost = myhost.com
remoteuser = mywork@email.com
remotepasseval = keyring.get_password('email', 'work')
```

My offlineimap.py file is just

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import keyring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer the error:

```
$sudo pip install keyring
```

and if that does not work for you,

0) create password in keychain like done [here in Retrieving Passwords section](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/the-homely-mutt/)

1) create file

```
$touch ~/offlineimap.py
```

**offlineimap.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re, subprocess
def get_keychain_pass(account=None, server=None):
    params = {
        'security': '/usr/bin/security',
        'command': 'find-internet-password',
        'account': account,
        'server': server,
        'keychain': '/Users/${USER}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain',
    }
    command = "sudo -u ${USER} %(security)s -v %(command)s -g -a %(account)s -s %(server)s %(keychain)s" % params
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    outtext = [l for l in output.splitlines()
               if l.startswith('password: ')][0]

    return re.match(r'password: "(.*)"', outtext).group(1)
```

2) edit line in your

**.offlineimaprc**

```
pythonfile = ~/offlineimap.py
```

3) and update remote sections

```
remotepasseval = get_keychain_pass(account="testUser@company.com", server="sub.domain.com")
```

4) if still having problems, try to change the command parameter in **offlineimap.py** file to

```
find-generic-password
```

5) correct your **Label string** and run it just once during start

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.andypierz.offlineimap</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/offlineimap -u quiet</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

6) load it

```
launchctl load com.andypierz.offlineimap.plist
```